# user-data on windows nano server in AWS, is executed with errors

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nano-server

I am executing a powershell script as user-data, on a windows nano server. I post this error on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247914&tstart=0) too.

The error is this line:

```
Install-Package -ProviderName NanoServerPackage -Name Microsoft-NanoServer-IIS-Package -Force
```

It's not executed, because this package is not found when is running on instance launch, but it's found correctly when I executed in a powershell command.

To check this, I was done the following:

1.- I checked the ps1 created by AWS. It's fine.
2.- I run the same script in a powershell console, in an empty nano server, with the same configuration; and it works fine
3.- I created a ps1, in an empty nano server, with the same configuration, and run it with remote powershell, and it works fine too
4.- I created a ps1 in my machine, and executed with remote "Invoke-Command" to an empty nano server, with same configuration, and works fine too.

The log shows this:
[log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/personal-vladimir-venegas/powershell-error/log-powershell.txt)

This is my script **edit**:
[script](https://s3.amazonaws.com/personal-vladimir-venegas/powershell-error/run2.ps1)

```
echo "$(Get-Date): Iniciando script"
echo "$(Get-Date): Estableciendo ExecutionPolicy"
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
echo "$(Get-Date): Instalando PackageProvider NuGet"
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
echo "$(Get-Date): Instalando PackageProvider NanoServerPackage"
Install-PackageProvider -Name NanoServerPackage -Scope AllUsers -Force
echo "$(Get-Date): Revisando que NanoServerPackage se haya instalado correctamente"
get-package
echo "$(Get-Date): Instalando Package Microsoft-NanoServer-IIS-Package"
Install-Package -ProviderName NanoServerPackage -Name Microsoft-NanoServer-IIS-Package -Force
echo "$(Get-Date): Importando Modulo IISAdministration"
Import-module IISAdministration -Global -Force
Start-Service WAS
Start-Service W3SVC
echo "$(Get-Date): Instalando Packete AWSPowerShell.NetCore"
Install-Package -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -Source https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/ -ProviderName NuGet -ExcludeVersion -Force
echo "$(Get-Date): Importando Modulo AWSPowerShell.NetCore"
Import-Module AWSPowerShell.NetCore -Force
echo "$(Get-Date): Iniciando servicios y copiando datos"
Copy-S3Object -BucketName demo-bucket-nanoserver -Key index.zip -LocalFile C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.zip
Expand-Archive C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.zip C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ -Force
Remove-Item C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.zip
echo "$(Get-Date): Fin del sistema"
```

What is the error? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: does it have the nanoserverpackage provider? also, previously `Microsoft-NanoServer-IIS-Package` was dependent on `Microsoft-NanoServer-Storage-Package` or something like that. https://github.com/OneGet/NanoServerPackage/issues/2

Comment: yes, I do......